# Is there a way to generate redshift sql?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, visio, lucidchart

I have a visio .vdx for the design of the my data warehouse with Lucidchart. Is there a way to generate redshift sql from that ?

What would be the best tool to work with Redshift data modeling ?

If those sql generator can generate tables for special visio stencil, like http://www.visualdatavault.com

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Redshift is (mostly) compatible with PostgreSQL, so any tool that can introspect PostgreSQL tables should work with Redshift.

One things to note -- constraints and foreign keys are not enforced in Redshift.

Comment: Column compression encodings, distkeys and sortkeys are also critical to the schema and probably aren't supported by such tools.